# Store data into two database engines

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, microservices, consistency

It's not about a question related about "one database per microservice" pattern neither master-slave database engine.

Currently, it's comming in my mind using two data storage systems:

1. An index engine (elasticsearch or solr): make full-text searches.
2. Document based engine (mongo): make slightly traditional queries.

I know there are several mechanisms to get this:

1. using "connectors": plugins are attached to main database engine and data is automatically moved to the other database engine (for example, from mongo to elasticsearch).
2. using message delivery engine (like kafka streams, flink...).

Nevertheless, there are systems that doesn't quite fit well using those above mechanisms.

1. I need received data is stored into both data engines. I'm not able data is processed asynchronously (via a connector, or using kafka streams or flink).

Here arise some issues:

```
                                                            mongo
                                                           ┌────┬──────────────┐
                                                           │    │              │
                                           ┌──────────────►│    │ stored entity│
                                           │               └────┴──────────────┘
                                           │
                          ┌──────────────┐ │
                          │   service    │ │
received-entity ────────► │ (digested-   ├─┤
                          │   entity)    │ │
                          └──────────────┘ │                elasticsearch
                                           │               ┌────┬──────────────┐
                                           │               │    │              │
                                           └─────XXXXXXX──►│    │              │
                                                    │      └────┴──────────────┘
                                                    │
                                                    ▼

                                               crashes here
```

As you can expect I need to see it as a transaction, without using an transaction. I mean, I need to eventually get consistency between two database engines.

The question:

Is there any well defined way to deal with those issues?

I hope I've explained well.

Comment: Asynchronously processing a durable log of changes can most definitely guarantee eventual consistency.  It's not clear what level of consistency you actually want (strong or eventual).

Comment: I need to get strong level of consistency.

Comment: Then what do you mean by "I need to eventually get consistency"?